# Local React, Node / Express Heroku Issue

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku

I'm new to React + Node / Express dev.

- I have a react client that I am running locally only http://localhost:3000/
- I've managed to deploy my Node + Express server on Heroku and the server is working
- However when I run requests from the local react app e.g. try to register, login with my app, the requests are not going through.

The get requests are working fine but with post requests I get this type of response on the console on Heroku:

at=info **method=OPTIONS** path="/login" host=***host-name-here*** request_id=**id here** fwd="**ip here**" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=204 bytes=301 protocol=https

instead of any post request, i just get method = Options.

Would love to debug + understand more about this issue. Thank you!

Comment: Check your browser console. sounds like a preflight request.

Answer (score 0):

Look through the code where it sends the POST request. If it is only sending an OPTIONS request, it could be that it is only sending an OPTIONS request, or that it is sending OPTIONS instead of POST.

The code may be encountering an error that causes it to stop before sending the POST request, so look in the browser's javascript console in developer options (Ctrl+Shift+K/I), to see if there are any javascript errors after the app sends the OPTIONS request, as a starting point.